# Java says I must return an Object, but I'm throwing exceptions

Tags: java, exception, return, try-catch

So I'm trying to catch exceptions where I can't return a Directory, but Java won't let me. How do I structure the code so that Java will let me run it?

```
public Directory pathToDir(String path) throws Exception {
    String[] arrayPath = path.split("/");
    Directory cwd_copy = FileSystem.getRoot();
    try {
        // full path
        if (path.startsWith("/")) {
            for (int x = 1; x < arrayPath.length; x++) {
                if (stuff) {
                } else {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
        }
        return cwd_copy;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        pathErrorMsg();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you **may** be throwing an exception, but then you catch it and do nothing with it! If you step through that code logically, you'll see that there are possible pathways for the method to end without a Directory being returned and for no exceptions to be thrown. That won't fly.

Consider instead,....

```
public Directory pathToDir(String path) throws PathToDirException {
    String[] arrayPath = path.split("/");
    Directory cwd_copy = FileSystem.getRoot();
    // full path
    if (path.startsWith("/")) {
        for (int x = 1; x < arrayPath.length; x++) {
            if (stuff) {
            } else {
                throw new PathToDirException( /* some text goes in here! */ );
            }
        }
    }
    return cwd_copy;
}
```

Where PathToDirException is a checked exception class you've created for problems with this method/class.

Or if you have a try/catch block in the method, and need to then throw an exception, throw your new Exception class, but pass the caught exception into your new exception as a constructor parameter.

Comment: @gnawgnaw: your code doesn't make sense -- you throw and catch plain exceptions. There's never any situation where you'd want to do  this, that I can imagine. Why on earth are you doing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you need a return at the end of your method (in case you catch an `Exception` instead of returning `cwd_copy`)

```
  return cwd_copy; // <-- this didn't happen.
} catch (Exception e) {
  pathErrorMsg();
  // return null; // <-- you could return here.
}
return null; // <-- so you need something. null or cwd_copy
```

Or add a return in the `catch` block.

Comment: Or return null out of the catch clause.

Answer (score 1):

Because an exception *could be* caught<sup>1</sup>, a value must still be returned from the `catch` path.

```
try {
   maybeThrowException();
   return X;
} 
catch (Exception e) {
   // But what is returned here?
}
```

Either don't catch the exception, [re]throw an exception, or return a value in the case when the catch block is entered.

Since the method is declared to throw an Exception, it probably should throw one on failure - the method contract should specify the result in such a case.

---

<sup>1</sup> Java actually isn't that smart, even if it is a logical way to think about it. The try/catch is treated like an if/else here and *all* branches must logically lead to a `return` (or `throw`). It would still be a compiler error even if the try was *empty* and could *never* throw an exception. Consider the following comparison:

```
if (true) {
    return X;
} else {
    // But what is returned here?
    // (Java does not consider that this can never be reached,
    //  just as it does not logically consider the content of a `try`.)
}
```